# where are packeges from Ubuntu Software Center downloaded to?

Tags: software-center, package-management, installed-programs

the location of the downloaded/installed programs and packages from software Center?

Comment: i don't want the equivalent of "C:\Programs". on Windows u can download an installer and then use that installer later to install the program on another PC. i don't wifi connection all the time so i want to be able to download the installers once and use them many times

Comment: @muru I'm not sure that answers the question, the OP wants to know where the .deb installer (or whatever) is downloaded to.

Comment: @Seth Isn't `/var/cache/apt/archives` where the .deb files gets downloaded to?

Comment: @muru "Program Files" is where Windows applications store their executables and other files necessary for their operation, not where they are downloaded too. (I'm referring to your "possible duplicate" comment, in case you thought I was referring to your answer).

Answer (score 0):

The command `dpkg -L <package>` will display the files associated with the given package.

Sample output of
`$ dpkg -L vim
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/vim.basic
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/vim
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/vim
/usr/share/bug/vim/presubj
/usr/share/bug/vim/script
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/vim`

Answer (score 0):

The package files that Software Center and other package management tools download are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. However, just picking up the packages from there won't do you much good. See [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) and understand that the Windows way of doing things does not always apply here.